# django model form, restrict choices based on value in ForeignKey model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have two models: `League` and `Team`. `Team` has a foreign key link to `League`. I want to be able to set choices available for the `Team` based on values stored in `League`. Specifically:

```
class League(models.Model):
    number_of_teams = models.IntegerField()

class Team(models.Model):
    league = models.ForeignKey(League)
    draft_slot = models.IntegerField(choices=[(i+1,i+1) for i in range(?????????)])
```

I recognize I cannot accurately define my `draft_slot.choices` in the `Team` model. So I would expect to set up `Team` like so:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    league = models.ForeignKey(League)
    draft_slot = models.IntegerField()
```

I have set up a `ModelForm` of `Team`:

```
class TeamModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Team
```

And a view of the `Team` `ModelForm`:

```
def SetupTeam(request, fanatic_slug=None, league_slug=None):
    league = League.objects.get(slug=league_slug)
    form = TeamModelForm()
    return render_to_response('league/addteam.html', {
        'form': form
    }, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

What foo do I need in order to use `league.id`, `league.number_of_teams` so the view of `TeamModelForm` prepopulates `team.league` and also renders a field to represent `team.draft_slot` to look like

```
draft_slot = models.IntegerField(choices=[(i+1,i+1) for i in range(league.number_of_teams+1)])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the working answer:

```
class TeamModelForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TeamModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance:
            n = self.instance.number_of_teams
            self.fields['draft_position'].widget.choices = [(i+1,i+1) for i in range(n)]

    class Meta:
        model = Team
        widgets = {'draft_position': Select(choices=())}
```

Comment: I carefully stepped through the code. If I set n = self.instance.league.number of teams, I get a number I can iterate over. The self.fields.['draft_slot'].choices fails. I have tried to set it equal to 1, to (1,1) to ((1,1),) as well as the given code. The code fails to provide the classic drop down list of choices when TeamModelForm is viewed. Everything else looks great.

Comment: @cole See the refined code above. Notice the `self.fields['draft_slot'].widget.choices`, instead of `self.fields['draft_slot'].choices`. Tell me if it works.

Comment: You were very close! It worked after I added the following line to class Meta: widgets = {'draft_position': Select(choices=())}

Comment: @Cole Well that's good news! I'll revise the code to reflect what you said.

Comment: The problem is now that team.name is set to the league name for some reason, and the form doesn't validate.

Comment: @Cole there is no `name` field on your models.