# How to restrict Foreign Key choices to another Foreign Key in the same model

Tags: python, django, database-design, django-models

I'm making a django application and I'm facing an issue. I am trying to define a model where one `ForeignKey` would be depending on another `ForeignKey`.

### Description part

My application is about making choices.

So let's say you have a `decision` to make, a `decision` has multiple `choice`s, and a `choice` has a `status` (because of other constraints).

A `status` can be used on multiple `choices`, but a `status` can be relevant only for one `decision`, the same one the `choice` is linked to.

### Database schema

It isn't fixed and might be changed if needed :

```
,____________,                  ,____________,
|            | 1, n        1, 1 |            |
|  Decision  |------------------|   Status   |
|____________|                  |____________|
      |                                |
      | 1, n                           | 1, n
      |                                |
      | 1, 1                           |
,_____|______,                         |
|            | 1, 1                    |
|   Choice   |-------------------------'
|____________|
```

### Code

And here is my current (simplified) (*not working*) code :

```
class Decision (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField (max_length = 63)

class Status (models.Model):
    value = models.CharField (max_length = 63)
    decision = models.ForeignKey (Decision)

class Choice (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField (max_length = 63)

    decision = models.ForeignKey (Decision)
    status = models.ForeignKey (Status, limit_choices_to = {'decision' : decision})
```

The important part here being the `limit_choices_to = {'decision' : decision}`.

### Extra info

I found another SO question ([In django, how to limit choices of a foreignfield based on another field in the same model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123294/in-django-how-to-limit-choices-of-a-foreignfield-based-on-another-field-in-the)) dealing about the same question, but the question is becoming old, and the best answer was relying on an external app ([django-smart-selects](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects/commits/master)).

I'd rather not have to use something external, and I cannot see why something as simple as a 3-table relationship cannot be solved using only Django !

If someone has any solution, or any suggestion, please tell me.

Comment: Did you look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13076043/1628832) ?

Comment: @karthikr This answer is applying on a form when I would like to apply it directly to the model (simplifying admin management at the same time). But if that's not possible, this is probably the path I'll choose.

Comment: well you can do the same in the admin forms too.. I know its redundant, but till you find a better way, this could work

Comment: Yeah, sure, and this is what I'm going to do if I can't find anything else. But I was hoping another more direct solution would be possible. Thanks for your answer, though.

Comment: This cannot be done at the model level; it can only be done at the form level and at the database level.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Why ? Could you consider adding an answer ? And then why is it possible with `django-smart-selects` ?

Comment: @Jerska it's not possible with `django-smart-selects`, because it doesn't work at the model level. It works at the Form level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Django, but I if you are trying to solve the "same one the choice is linked to" part of the problem, this is how it can be done at the database level:

[image]

Note the usage of identifying relationships, so the `DecisionId` is migrated down both "branches" and merged at the "bottom". So if a `Choice` has `Status`, they both must be linked to the same `Decision`.

Comment: The question itself is CW, so all answers are going to be CW as well.

Comment: Well, I don't see any way to connect two foreign keys from different tables together in django, but it seems to be the correct database-design answer.

Answer (score 3):

What you're asking is not possible, at least not within the boundaries you've set (no forms, no external libraries). The `status` field of your `Choice` model is a Foreign Key, a relationship between two tables… it doesn't deal with filtering itself, simply put – it doesn't have this feature. And this isn't a *django* thing, this is a *database* thing. The Django ORM isn't as far away from the database as you probably think, it's brilliant but it's not magic.

Some of the available solutions are:

- Do it at the FormField level by filtering the queryset
- Use something like *[django-smart-selects](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects)* (this does the above)
- Override `save` on your model, add the check there and throw an error if it fails
- Make `status` a property and do validation checks on it when it's set

If you go with `FormField` method as well as overriding `save` you'll have the benefit of knowing there's no way a `Choice` can be saved it it violates this constraint, from either the user's end (filling out a form) or the back end (code that calls `.save()` on a `Choice` instance.

Comment: Well, your answer is the kind of answer I was expecting, even if I would have loved to see a solution at the model level. There goes my bounty. Thanks for the multiple solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you need here is a `through` model, like so:

```
class Choice (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField (max_length = 63)
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status)
    decision = models.ForeignKey(Decision)

class Status(Models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Decision(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 63)
    choices = models.ManyToManyField(Status, through = "Choice")
```

This way, every decision has many choices, each of which has only one status. You could do a query like:
`my_decision.choices.all()` or `my_status.decision_set.all()`

I suggest you take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/models/) for an example on how to use through models

Comment: I like this answer, because it made me discover the `through` parameter, and this is actually something very interesting. But your answer isn't actually what I was looking for, since it is still allowing any status to be linked to a choice, even if there is now a relationship between the status and the decision that is now dependent on the choices already made, which is quite interesting. I wanted a choice status to be limited by its decision.
But as pointed out by Matt, the problem seems like not being solvable at the model level in Django, as I thought.

Answer (score 0):

In the following statement `decision` is neither a callable nor a `models.Q` object:

```
status = models.ForeignKey (Status, limit_choices_to = {'decision' : decision})
```

here is a way to represent your data:

```
class Decision(models.Model):
    ...

# a status is relevant for only one decision
# there may be more than one Status per Decision.
class Status(Models.Model):
    decision = models.ForeignKey(Decision)

# each choice is linked to one decision and has a status.
class Choice (models.Model):
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status)
    # if status is mandatory, then you can get the decision
    # from status.decision. per se, this fk could be optional.
    decision = models.ForeignKey(Decision)
```

here is another one:

```
class Decision(models.Model):
    ...

# a decision has multiple choices
# a choice pertains to only one decision
class Choice (models.Model):
    decision = models.ForeignKey(Decision)

# each status is relevant to one decision
# and may encompass multiple choices.
class Status(Models.Model):
    decision = models.ForeignKey(Decision)
    # problem with this representation is that this allows for
    # a choice to be linked to multiple statuses.
    # this happens when using M2M instead of ForeignKey.
    choices = models.ManyToManyField(Choice)
```

Comment: Your first answer is actually what I already had, and your second is just removing constraints, making a `ManyToMany` relationship where there is a `OneToMany`. But you knew it when posting, as I can tell with your comments. Thanks for your answer, though.

Comment: the first representation given is normal and that would be equivalent to @branko-dimitrijevic's answer.